# KnockoutJS: setting checked value to something other than true or false

Tags: knockout.js

When I use 'value' with a select, I can store a reference to an model as the value.

`<select data-bind="value: selectedOption,
    attr: {name: $parent.name},
    options: options,
</select>`

The above works very well. The model is stored in a parent model, so I can access all of it's properties elsewhere. With a checked, I can only store true and false:

`<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedOption, checkedValue: $data" />`

In this case, `$parent.selectedOption` is an observable, and my assumption is that I should be able to write in whatever data I want (in this case $data, which references the model at the current scope).

Why is KO not passing in the model as a value, only true/false?

Edit: When I switch `selectedOption` to an observable array, it passes in whatever I want just fine... but I don't want to use an array.

Edit 2: On the input, if I change the `value` or `checkedValue` data bindings to 'foo', it still just returns true or false. It's like I can't override the boolean values.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Knockout?

Comment: What is the context of the problem? Do you have multiple check boxes or just one? What do they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is KO not passing in the model as a value, only true/false?

Because you've provided it with a (regular) observable, Knockout is assuming that you simply want to know whether that checkbox is checked or not. After all, a check box can only have two states.

If however, you give it an observable **array**, Knockout will add/remove the `checkedValue` from the array when you interact with the checkbox.

Comment: Weird. I just assumed that checkedValue would allow me to override the default boolean behaviour. It wasn't clear in the docs that an array must be used.

Comment: Look at the very last paragraph of the docs. `If your checkedValue parameter is an observable value, whenever the value changes and the element is currently checked, the binding will update the checked model property. For checkboxes, it will remove the old value from the array and add the new value. For radio buttons, it will just update the model value.` Notice how they assume you're using an array if you're expecting to use the checkedValue.

Comment: If you've only got one checkbox then you probably **should** just use an observable boolean that indicates whether it is checked or not. You could use this boolean in other places to determine whether you get the value it represents or null or undefined or a default etc etc.